# Passing intent position

Tags: android, android-intent, position

I'm trying to pass the ListView position via intent and not the id.  Is there anyway of doing this.  When I delete an item, i want to pass the changed position.  Currently, both the position and id are the same.

If there's a better way (i.e. if statement in 2nd view), please explain.

```
public class MyCollection extends Activity {

private ListView listView;
List<MyMovieDataModel> movieList;
MyDatabase database;
MyMovieAdapter myMovieAdapter;
private static final String TAG = "popularmovies";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_collection_main);

    database = new MyDatabase(this);
    movieList = database.getAllItems();
    myMovieAdapter = new MyMovieAdapter(this, R.layout.my_collection_row, movieList);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myCollection_listView);
    listView.setAdapter(myMovieAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyCollection.this, MyDetailView.class);
            intent.putExtra("movie", position);
            Log.d(TAG, "Intent position: " + position);

            Log.d(TAG, "Intent id: " + id);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    clickToDetail();
}

public void clickToDetail() {

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyCollection.this, MyDetailView.class);
            intent.putExtra("movie", position);
            Log.d(TAG, "Intent position: " + position);
            Log.d(TAG, "Intent id: " + id);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

This is from 2nd view:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            mPosition = bundle.getInt("movie");
            Log.d(TAG, "Bundle mPosition: " + mPosition);
        }

        moviePosition = (int) (mPosition + 1);
        Log.d(TAG, "Bundle moviePosition: " + moviePosition);

        MyDatabase myDatabase = new MyDatabase(this);
        database = myDatabase.getWritableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + MyDatabase.DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE _id = " + moviePosition;
        Log.d(TAG, "SQL Query Position: " + moviePosition);
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    idList.add(cursor.getInt(0));
                    list.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    list.add(cursor.getString(2));
                    list.add(cursor.getString(3));
                    list.add(cursor.getString(4));
                    //list.add(cursor.getString(5));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        //Link & Set Detail Views//
        detailID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailID);
        detailID.setText(cursor.getString(0));

        detailTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
        detailTitle.setText(cursor.getString(1));

        detailDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailDate);
        detailDate.setText(cursor.getString(2));

        detailRating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailRating);
        detailRating.setText(cursor.getString(3));

        detailSynopsis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailSynopsis);
        detailSynopsis.setText(cursor.getString(4));

        //detailPoster = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detailPoster);
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem, exactly?

Comment: Your code is right what is problem you are?

Comment: When I delete listview items, i am getting "Index 0 requested, with a size of o".  It is pulling the deleted id.  I was hoping maybe I should either pass the correct position or do an if statement with offset or something.  How did I get neg rep so quickly, lol?

Comment: you should pass an `id`, and your adapter should use stable ids, see `Adapter#hasStableIds`

Comment: i will give that a try, pskink.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are correctly passing item's position through intent; all you need to do is in your `MyDetailView`, call

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("movie", 0);
```

where "movie" has to be the same String value as you specified when putting extra into intent, and 0 is the default value that will be passed if there is no value associated with the key(in this case "movie"). Then you can receive correct item's position.

Comment: Thanks for response.  I don't think i'm passing the correct position.  From my log tags, the id should always be the same, but i was hoping the position would change based on deletion.  Is that not the case?  I'm a little new to this.

Comment: Can you possibly post your entire codes in `MyCollection` class so that we can have little more idea about your situation?